# Changing module to "es2015" on tsconfig.json i get "Unexpected token import" when running protractor

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I'm trying to run protractor but transpiling typescript using es2015 module for my Angular 2 application. This works fine for the application itself but it fails with protractor.

When using module es2015 in my tsconfig I get the following error:

```
(node:9096) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[15:23:36] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[15:23:36] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:23:40] E/launcher - Error: C:\xxx\test1.e2e.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { browser, element, by, $ } from 'protractor';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\xxx\ts-node\src\index.ts:406:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\vmob-apps\purple-chicken\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:409:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
[15:23:40] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "",
        "declaration": false,        
        "target": "es5",
        "mapRoot": "./",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "types": [
            "jasmine",
            "node"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist",
        "**/*.ngfactory.ts",
        "**/*.shim.ts",
        "src/main*.ts"
    ],
    "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
        "forkChecker": true,
        "useWebpackText": true
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "genDir": ".",
        "entryModule": "src/app/app.module#AppModule"
    }    
}
```

When changing it to commonjs it works fine.

Is is there anything I need to add in my protractor config to support it? Or is there a way I can target a seperate tsconfig file?

Thanks!

EDIT: I've figured out how to target a seperate tsconfig file, you can do it via the ts-node require and pass in some options. ts-node is what actually transpiles typescript, was a struggle trying to figure out what made it magically transpile.

`require('ts-node').register({
  lazy: true,
  project: './config/tsconfig-commonjs.json'
});`